# What Should i do to get PyQt4 working?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, pyqt4

Installed python-qt4 and pyqt4-dev-tools packages on ubuntu

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v8.0 but the PyQt4.QtGui module requires API v7.1
```

What Should i do to get PyQt4 working?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your apt source list messed up. Go **apt-get update** and **apt-get upgrade pyqt* python-qt4** and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I cleaned, erased all the files of installation and started all over again following these instructions:

> If you want to use it with different version of python than 2.7 than
>   replace every 2.7 in instructions below with the version you are using
>   and it should work (tested with 2.6 and 3).
>
> First, you need some prerequities: sudo apt-get install python-pip
>   python2.7-dev libxext-dev python-qt4 qt4-dev-tools build-essential
>
> Then, try to install the PyQt and SIP using pip (it fails but it
>   downloads the required packages to your ~/build/ folder). pip install
>   PyQt pip install SIP
>
> After that go to ~/build/SIP and install it cd ~/build/SIP python2.7
>   configure.py make sudo make install
>
> Finally go to ~/build/PyQt and install it Note: as PyQt is a big
>   project - building it may take some time.. cd ~/build/PyQt python2.7
>   configure.py make sudo make install

**Source:** http://problemssol.blogspot.com/2010/12/compile-and-install-pyqt4-for-python27.html